# dynamic programming problem, finding optimal visits to stores

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Say we have a list of stores that contain some value when visited. 
E.g. store_value = [2,4,9,1,4,2].

Running from store to store to collect the value has some cost, e.g. run_cost = [0,1,2,3,1,2].
That is if I run to collect value 9 at store i = 3 (not 0-indexed), it will have the cost 2, which means i wouldn't have been able to visit the 2 previous stores, because of the cost required. Consider it amount rested before running to store i.

Now using dynamic programming, we could say V(x,i), where V(0,i) is the maximal value obtainable after the first i stores, if we DO NOT run to store i. V(1,i) is the maximal value obtainable after the first i stores, if we DO run to store i.

What would P(0,i) and P(1,i) running from store i = 1..6 look like?

I tried running the algorithm, but something tells me i am doing something wrong.
From what i could gather:

P(0,1) = 0, P(1,1) = 2

*from here on this is where i think im wrong:*
P(0,2) = 2, P(1,2) = 4 ... and so forth

If someone could help me understand how i should think about this problem, i'd appreciate it a lot.

Comment: If you run to store 3, *why* couldn't you visit the two previous stores?  You just say "because of the cost required", but give no specification of this "cost" resource, which seems to be different from the "value" of the store.

Comment: You say you "tried running the algorithm", but there's no referent for "the algorithm".  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here.  We can't repair code you haven't posted.

Comment: You specify the cost of running to a store as depending only upon that store number; other places, you imply that the cost is dependent on the starting point, or on previous stops.

Answer (score 0):

An easier formulation would be to define `V(i)` as the maximum value that can be achieved with stores `1..i`. The recursive definition is then:

```
V(i) = max(
           V(i - 1),                                //do not visit store i
           store_value[i] + V(i - run_cost[i] - 1)  //visit store i
       )
```

Some care needs to be taken when `run_cost` is `0`.